# Add email next to token in Laravel forgot password template email link

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, forgot-password

I'm using Laravel 8.5 with authentication system. When user wants to change password it sends an email with link. Default email contains link which looks like this:

```
http://mywebsite/api/forgot-password?token=2ccece360b031db4dcadea0cbdf8dd47a1712632b727487a7226f19f8f607cc7&email=MyEmail%40gmail.com
```

I did some changes in email template. In `ResetPasswordNotification.php` I added this:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->subject('MyApp password reset')
                    ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
                    ->action('Reset Password', $this->url)
                    ->line('This password reset link will expire in 60 minutes.')                    
                    ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
    }
```

and in `User.php` I have:

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {    
        $url = 'http://mywebsite/en/change-password?token=' . $token;    
        $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($url));
    }
```

and now I receive this link:

```
http://mywebsite/en/change-password?token=8f87fc2d504507as385b4c47cb015cee4192749d3f1d641863524d513abb2a39
```

which only contains token and not email. How do I add email to this so it would look something like this:

```
http://mywebsite/en/change-password?token=8f87fc2d504507as385b4c47cb015cee4192749d3f1d641863524d513abb2a39&email=UserEmail@gmail.com
```

Comment: You'd simply change `$url = 'http://mywebsite/en/change-password?token=' . $token;` to `$url = 'http://mywebsite/en/change-password?token=' . $token . '&email=' . $this->email;` (since `$this` would reference a User in `User.php`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `$this->email` next to `$token`.

```php
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{    
    $url = 'http://mywebsite/en/change-password?token=' . $token . '&email=' . $this->email;    
    $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($url));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try passing email to the url.

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{    
    $url = 'http://mywebsite/en/change-password?token=' . $token . '&email=' .$this->email;    
    $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($url));
}
```

Comment: Thanks to Tim Lewis it now works!

$url = 'http://mywebsite/en/change-password?token=' . $token . '&email=' . $this->email;